# Why returns one of the values?

Tags: c#

The compiler returns one of the values( in my example is "рублей"). Why is this so? Thank you for answer.
The code here:

```
public static class PluralizeTask
    {
        public static string PluralizeRubles(int count)
        {
            string numString = count.ToString();
            char endOfstring = numString[numString.Length - 1];
            int numEndOfstring = endOfstring;
            {
                if (numEndOfstring == 1) return "рубль";
                else if (numEndOfstring > 1 && numEndOfstring < 5) return "рубля";
                else return "рублей";
            }
         }
    }
```

Comment: Because neither of the two `if` conditions evaluated to `true`

Comment: You are taking the last character of a string and assigning it to an `int`. I'm guessing that is not doing what you think it is doing.

Comment: What is the argument you pass to the `PluralizeRubles` function?

Comment: You're assigning a `char` to an `int`. The `char` value `1` is the [start of header](http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-control-characters/start-of-header-ascii-code-1.html) character. I don't think your string ends with that.

Comment: .NET 4.5 has a built-in pluralization library; see https://jamesmccaffrey.wordpress.com/2015/03/14/singular-and-plural-words-using-net-pluralizationservices/ I don't know if it works for your use case, though.

Comment: @RogerLipscombe This isn't going to work for Russian and several other languages that pluralize differently depending on the actual number of things. In Russian there are two plural endings - one for "small plural" (two through five) and another one for numbers above five. Moreover, numbers ending in one, but not in eleven, are not pluralized at all, and numbers ending in two through five, but not twelve through fifteen, use "small plural" ending. The interface for `PluralizationService` takes a word without the corresponding number, so it cannot possibly provide the required functionality.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, fair enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the way you construct `numEndOfstring`: you take an integer, convert it to a sequence of characters, and then pick the last *character* from it. This `int` value is going to be in the range `'0'`..`'9'`, inclusive. Hence, `221` is not going to produce `1`, it is going to produce `'1'` (note single quotes).

To fix this problem, use this expression:

```
int numEndOfstring = count % 10;
```

Note that your pluralization is going to remain incorrect according to the rules of Russian language, because it would not puralize teen numbers correctly (i.e. "11 рубль", "12 рубля", etc.) You need to consider the last two digits of the number in order to do this correctly. You get the number that represents the last two digits with

```
int lastTwoDigits = count % 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the line:

```
int numEndOfstring = endOfstring;
```

Here you take the last char in a string and assign *it number* to a `numEndOfString`. So for char `0` you assign its number which is 48 this you end with `numEndOfString` holding a 48 (instead of 0). You can get around this by several means. One is the way which @dasblinkenlight suggest. Others you might sometimes want to use is to do parsing `int numEndOfstring = int.Parse(endOfstring)` (works even with strings), or `int numEndOfstring = endOfstring - '0'` or `int numEndOfstring = endOfstring - 48`. Actually both last are practically the same. The magic here is the fact that you compute how far is your char from zero (which has is char number 48). However beware! This will happily take any char e.g. 't' and you might really surprising results and/or silent errors hard to find, so be sure to check what you are really converting